# nav2d Navigator failing to create path

Tags: ros, turtlebot, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to use nav2d with the turtlebot robot, in order to map an unknown room. I was able to modify the tutorial3.launch file and the costmap is created without problems. But when i try to add a goal in Rviz, the robot don't move and it show

```
[ERROR]: Prepare failed!
```

I also tried to use

```
rosservice call /StartMapping 3
```

but it only print `response: 0` and shut down.

Here is my rqt_graph : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/270785rosgraph.png

EDIT :
The mapper log show the following error

```
[[33m[ WARN] [1444902817.579649858]: Failed to compute odometry pose, skipping scan ("base_laser_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. )^[[0m
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219046/nav2d-navigator-failing-to-create-path/) by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Prepare" means, that the Navigator tries to get a map and the robot's position from the Mapper. You should check if a map is build (global map from Mapper, not local costmap from the Operator).

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-10-15**:
Thanks for your answer, it seems that the Mapper node is not creating the map. It seems that it is because 3 topic it subscribe to are not published : /tf_static , /karto_in and /initialpose.
Which node is supposed to publish those 3 topic ?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-10-15**:
I don't think it is related to these 3 topics. /tf_static is from tf and only used for static transforms, /karto_in and /initialpose are only needed in a multi-robot scenario. You could set the Mapper's log level to debug. And check for errors when you call the get_map service.

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-10-15**:
Thanks for your anwers.
May i ask how to do that ? i was able to change the Mapper's log level with `rosservice call /mapper ros debug`, but i don't know how to call the get_map service as it is not listed in rosservice list, only /GetMap/get_loggers and /GetMap/set_logger_level

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-10-15**:
I usually use the 'rqt_console' tool directly to change the log level of a node. There has to be a service 'get_map', which is called by the Navigator in Prepare-Phase. Looks like your mapper is not running correctly. Are there any messages from the mapper during startup?

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-10-15**:
No messages during startup, sadly :-(
It only show around 20 time a sec the following message in the Mapper log :

```
[[33m[ WARN] [1444902817.579649858]: Failed to compute odometry pose, skipping scan ("base_laser_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. )^[[0m
```

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-10-15**:
This seems to be the problem. All scans are skipped and not added to the map. Make sure that the parameters "laser_frame", "robot_frame" and "odometry_frame" are set according to your robot setup. You can use "rosrun tf view_frames" to inspect your current frame tree.

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-10-16**:
Thanks a lot for the answers, i was able to change the /laser_frame to the correct value.
It took me so long because thoses parameters are not listed in the `rosparam list /Mapper`
The map is now correctly created, but as the robot is not responding to goals, i may create another question :)

**Comment by [张京林](https://answers.ros.org/users/19842/%E5%BC%A0%E4%BA%AC%E6%9E%97/) on 2015-12-23**:
But how to set those three frames "laser_frame", "robot_frame" and "odometry_frame" ? I meet the same problem.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-12-27**:
The frame names are set at the [top-level-file](https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/blob/master/nav2d_tutorials/param/ros.yaml), so they are available to all nodes

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2016-01-04**:
You have to set thoses parameters inside the mapper.yaml or ros.yaml file you use if i remember correctly, will re-check when i have my robot available.